# HTTP status code for an effectless request

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I'm designing a small RESTfull API for a media player and encoder. There you can start, pause and stop a stream or recording.

Lets assume the service is idle - theres no encoding activity. Now the client sends a request to the service like

```
POST media.box/api/stream
action=stop
```

This obviously has no effect at the server side but the client should be noticed that theres something wrong with the request.

What HTTP status code is the most suitable for this case?

Comment: You should still return status code 200, as the request completed successfully.  To check whether the request had an effect on the server you should send a message on the http content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel that that is an error condition, you should consider returning 422 (Unprocessable Entity). It indicates that the request was received, but a semantic error in the request prevented it from being executed.

The other school of thought is that no-op requests like "stop everything!" when nothing is running should just say "Ok! Nothing is running anymore." and return gracefully. You'll have to decide which is right for your API.